# Ajax POST works in safari, but not in other browsers

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I've got an form which posts a form trough an ajax script to some PHP code. Strangely enough everything is working in Safari, but once i try it in either Firefox or Chrome the ajax call handles everything as an error, though the console doesn't show any errors.

```
    $('#newClearance').on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'modules/avas/library/avas_functions.php?action=newClearance',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data, status) {
            $('#formModal').modal('hide');
            $.notify(data, {type: 'success'});
            $.get(window.location)
                .done(function (r) {
                    var newDom = $(r);
                    $('#clearanceList').replaceWith($('#clearanceList', newDom));
                });
        },
        error: function (data,status,error) {
            $.notify(error, {type: 'danger'});
        }
    });
});
```

If I post the html form directly to the PHP script, everything goes well and the PHP script returns a success. It works in all browsers.

I really can't find the clue, especially as the same script, except for another form, is working perfectly fine in all browsers. Anybody a clue?

**Additional info**
Good thing to note might be that the form and jquery are placed in a modal, as you might notice form the code.

Comment: In the Chrome Devtools go to the network tab, select XHR (that's for Ajax) then submit your form to trigger the Ajax request. Can you see the request in the list of calls on that tab ? It should appear there and if you select the request on the list you'll have access to the response details, post them here so we can help you more.

Comment: Response in firefox: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data.
Cache-Control 
no-store, no-cache, must-reval…te, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection 
keep-alive
Content-Type 
application/json
Date 
Wed, 20 Jun 2018 21:51:59 GMT
Expires 
Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma 
no-cache
Server 
nginx/1.13.2
Transfer-Encoding 
chunked
X-Powered-By 
PHP/5.6.32

Comment: And Safari: Response
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Wed, 20 Jun 2018 21:53:33 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx/1.13.2
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.32
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Transfer-Encoding: Identity

Comment: As the message states, there's an error with the JSON data parsing in firefox. Can you paste here the request data from this call ?

Comment: Ok, think i'm getting closer to a solution. If I'm looking at the request payload in the devtools it looks like the value of the submit button, which is required by the PHP script to successfully execute the script, is missing in firefox and chrome, and not in safari.

Comment: **Firefox/Chrome**------WebKitFormBoundary1wC8WVdSpLWTJB3A
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="clearanceType"
D
------WebKitFormBoundary1wC8WVdSpLWTJB3A
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="callID"
1380
------WebKitFormBoundary1wC8WVdSpLWTJB3A
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="datepickerValue"
2018-06-22 23:30
------WebKitFormBoundary1wC8WVdSpLWTJB3A--

Comment: **SAFARI** 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="clearanceType"
D
------WebKitFormBoundary9RnmCzQzvVF4A2nJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="callID"
1380
------WebKitFormBoundary9RnmCzQzvVF4A2nJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="datepickerValue"
2018-06-22 23:30
------WebKitFormBoundary9RnmCzQzvVF4A2nJ
__Content-Disposition: form-data; name="addClearance"__
------WebKitFormBoundary9RnmCzQzvVF4A2nJ--

Answer (score 0):

What do your server logs say when it receives the request?

Comment: No errors thrown at all... Not in the PHP log, not in MySQL log.
I've just tried to see what's in the data variable by logging it to the console.
In firefox it logs {"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}, in safari it log's what it should log according to the PHP script (similar to success).
With the similar script, it's not the case! Still considering that it's something within the PHP code, except that when I'm posting the form directly without ajax everything runs smooth and it returns the JSON "success array"

Comment: No no sorry, what does your Apache2/Nginx log say?

Comment: Firefox:
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jun/2018:23:39:13 +0200] "POST /modules/avas/library/avas_functions.php?action=newClearance HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "http://marlinspike:7889/?m=avas&s=voyage&voyage=2" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"
Safari: 
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jun/2018:23:41:00 +0200] "POST /modules/avas/library/avas_functions.php?action=newClearance HTTP/1.1" 200 48 "http://marlinspike:7889/?m=avas&s=voyage&show=calls&poc=A1378" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.1.1 Safari/605.1.15"

Answer (score 0):

Part of the solution appears to be the "submit" button of the form, which was required by the PHP script to run. I've removed this condition in the PHP script, but still wondering why firefox/chrome doesn't POST the submit button and safari does.